# Set Alias to tables using stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables

- Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas
- Proceso.tmpUnidadesPresupuestadas

That I want is to set alias to `Proceso.tmpUnidadesPresupuestadas`(temporal table)  and`Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas` using stored procedure, the problem is I'm new using stored procedures I have something like:

```
--Getting registers of table Proceso.tmpUnidadesPresupuestadas
SELECT 
    Uni.keyCliente, Uni.keyCentro, Uni.keyMaterial, Uni.Periodo, Uni.Mes,
    Uni.UnidadesPresupuestadas, Uni.Plataforma, Uni.mdOrigenCarga, 
    Uni.mdUsuarioCarga, Uni.mdFechaCarga, Uni.bActivo
INTO 
    #tmpUnidadesPresupuestadas
FROM 
    Proceso.tmpUnidadesPresupuestadas Uni

--Insert in table Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas 
INSERT INTO Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas (num1, num2, etc) 
VALUES (#tmpUnidadesPresupuestadas.num1, #tmpUnidadesPresupuestadas.num2)
```

In other words I want to use alias to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO Destino (num1, num2, etc) 
VALUES (Origen.num1, Origen.num2)
```

Regards

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Do you mean you are trying to change your SELECT INTO statement into a stored procedure that uses variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert into a table from another table, you need to use the `INSERT INTO ..... SELECT .....` syntax - something like:

```
--Insert in table Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas 
INSERT INTO Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas (num1, num2, etc) 
    SELECT
        num1, num2, etc
    FROM
        #tmpUnidadesPresupuestadas
```

The `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ....` syntax can *only* be used if you have all the values as literals, parameters for your procedure, or in SQL Server variables (`@num1` etc.) - but **not** if you want to select values from another table

Comment: Exactly that I want, and thank you for complete explanation. Regards

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused about what an alias is. An alias is used to give a table or an object a temporary name that is only valid for the scope of that query. What you are describing sounds more like a synonym which is way to provide an alternate for a database object that is persistent.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine

Comment: So in my case I can use `INTO #tmpUnidadesPresupuestadas AS Origen` and new row like`Proceso.srcUnidadesPresupuestadas AS Destino`?

Comment: You can create a synonym for a temp table...but it doesn't make any sense to do so. The synonym will be invalid once the temp table is dropped. Wouldn't it have been a lot easier to just insert into the name of your temp table?

Comment: The "AS" argument means you are using an alias. Your terminology isn't right here.